# ERROR could not load library "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgres_fdw.so"

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, yum, postgres-fdw

I'm getting the following error when attempting to access a foreign table.

`ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgres_fdw.so": /usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgres_fdw.so: undefined symbol: TimestampDifferenceMilliseconds`

This was not a problem until yesterday, when someone used `yum` to update a bunch of stuff under `sudo` permissions.

The file, `postgres_fdw.so`, *is* in the listed location.

#### Relevant Information:

- I've been using `psql (11.11, server 11.5)` for a few months now.
- I had previously been using `psql (9.2.24, server 11.5)`
- foreign data wrappers had been constructed and linked before the update
- I'm running CentOS 7 (`centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64`)
- I am aware that there are at least two instances of psql installed on the server
- someone on sudo recently ran `yum update -y`; looking at the logs from the update, the following lines contain "`postgresql`"

```
Mar 05 10:00:22 Updated: postgresql-libs-9.2.24-4.el7_8.x86_64
Mar 05 10:00:22 Updated: postgresql11-libs-11.11-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
Mar 05 10:00:27 Updated: postgresql-9.2.24-4.el7_8.x86_64
Mar 05 10:02:36 Updated: postgresql11-11.11-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
Mar 05 10:02:45 Updated: postgresql11-server-11.11-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
Mar 05 10:06:11 Updated: postgresql11-contrib-11.11-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
Mar 05 10:06:22 Updated: postgresql-server-9.2.24-4.el7_8.x86_64
Mar 05 10:06:51 Updated: postgresql-contrib-9.2.24-4.el7_8.x86_64
Mar 05 10:06:54 Updated: postgresql10-libs-10.16-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11-11.html ... without having checked the respective source this may have just bitten you; there are three mentions of `postgres_fdw` in the changelog.

Comment: P.S.: This highlights the beauty of different environments (dev/test/UAT/prod)? :)

Comment: Per @tink, from release notes: "Both of these errors stemmed from incorrectly converting seconds-and-microseconds to milliseconds. Introduce a new API TimestampDifferenceMilliseconds() to make it easier to get this right in the future." Did you build the FDW from source or did you use the `-contrib` version?

Comment: 1. i don't know enough to implement different environments (dev/test/UAT/prod). 2. I don't know if I built the fdw from source or --contrib; I just used the CREATE EXTENSION command with the version of postgres I had installed.